# Warning messages after updating Cypress

Tags: cypress

Just updated Cypress through bash on Ubuntu 20.4 and the command

```
npx cypress open
```

caused these warnings:

```
[3775:0903/175043.894504:WARNING:vaapi_wrapper.cc(588)] VAAPI video acceleration not available for swiftshader
[3775:0903/175043.894944:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(440)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader
```

The pop up shows up but I'm afraid this will cause errors in my JS testing.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install`. I had the same issue as I changed my git branch. Running this command fixed my issue.